# How to put regex info into hash

Tags: regex, ruby, hash

I need to parse an Apache log file and output IP, URL, and URL status code into hashes but don't know how to put the elements into a hash.

My code uses regular expressions to get the info I need from each line of the log file:

```
line_array = File.readlines("access_log")
line_array.each { |line| }
#regexp
md = (/^([:\d\.]+) .*\[.*\].*\"[A-Z]+ *(.+) HTTP\S*\s(\d+)/).match(line)
ip = md[1]
url = md[2]
status = md[3]
```

Is my current code even on the right track to be able to do this?

I need the hashes to display the item and then the frequency of said item. So if we have the hash for ip addresses it will display the ip addresses in the log file followed the the frequency of that specific ip.

Comment: So what are the keys and what are the values in this hash?

Comment: Please provide input data and output expectations

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need the minimal code necessary to duplicate the problem, example input data and the desired output.

Comment: The Apache log format is well documented. There are pre-written regular expressions available to be used and there's sure to be some pre-written code to extract all the information in each line into a hash or an object, making it very easy to reuse the code, the data, or at least understand how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your md correctly returns an array of strings which is what you appear to be expecting, then try:

```
line_array = File.readlines("access_log")
line_array.each { |line| }
#regexp
md = (/^([:\d\.]+) .*\[.*\].*\"[A-Z]+ *(.+) HTTP\S*\s(\d+)/).match(line)
hash = Hash.new
hash[:ip] = md[1]
hash[:url] = md[2]
hash[:status] = md[3]
```

This will create a hash object with the three keys:

```
hash
=> { ip: 'whatever is in md[1]', url: 'whatever is in md[2]', status: 'whatever is in md[3]' }
```

Also just to highlight, by accessing md[1] you're accessing the second element of the array, if you want the first you need md[0]

Comment: thanks for the help, your answer helped with what I provided in my question. If I did md[0] it would populate with the whole regex find instead of the specific part of the regex im looking for. I appreciate the input

Comment: Also `match` returns a `MatchData` so you could use named capture groups and `MatchData#named_captures` which returns a `Hash`